Hide the letters randomly inside a collection
I'm learning Geo Nodes and wanted to make objects inside a collection randomly apear and disapear as they are (no loc, rot,or scale changes) using scene time node along my timeline so the letters come and go randomly as my timeline duration lasts!

I could come up with this setup using a single solid object but as is, random faces are hidden making the text not readabl which is not what i need!

I've searched for tutorials but found none as specific as what i need to accomplished here!
Thank you so much in advance for any help you guys can give me! Appreciated!

You could split the individual letters into instances using the Split to Instances node and then select and remove them as a whole.
Something like this:

